# Как настроить Drag and Drop в vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, drag-n-drop

Как настроить `Drag-and-Drop` в vue.js  из одной колонки в другую, а так же изменение порядка внутри одной колонки?

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы превели бы какой-то пример кода

Comment: возможно подойдёт [Vue.Draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable)